# Linear applications notation details

Tags: notation

I have much trouble in clearly understanding what sounds like simple notation in linear applications in physics. Based on this image

[image]

authors make the following develoment

[image]

which I would like to decipher, or even know exactly how it is called.

Comment: It means $\varphi$ is a map that takes the space $R_\mathbf{X} \times [t_0,t_\mathrm{final}[$ and maps it to the new space $R_\mathbf{x} \times [t_0,t_\mathrm{final}[$, i.e. the time remains unchanged, but the coordinates will be transformed in some given way. The second line just says any pair of $\mathbf{X}$ and $t$ transformes with $\varphi(\mathbf{X},t)$ to a new pair called $(\mathbf{x},t)$.

Comment: Thanks ! What about the cross ?

Comment: The symbol X between $R_X$ and $[t_0,t_{f}]$ is really confusing. It's just supposed to label R with the time interval.

Comment: Any difference between the two arrows (one of them has a small vertical bar at its root) ? Also, $:$ means 'maps' then ?

Comment: I'm going to say no difference. The first line is, "phi maps blah1 to blah2." The second line is (X,t) are taken/mapped by phi to (x,t). So one is talking about what $\phi$ does to the entire region, and the other about what $\phi$ does to the sub-region or state (X,x). And the : means "this is what it does;" or depending on context, "such that."

Comment: Maybe a better way of interpreting the ":" is as a symbol to introduce the map-- $\phi$ such that $\phi$ maps x to y."

Comment: Some parts of the notation are explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation)

Comment: @daniel while this is more mathematics than physics, maybe you can summarize your comments as an answer?

Comment: @mikuszefski This is also a kind of link I was looking for ! Thanks

Comment: The $\times$ is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) and the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) therein.

Comment: Concerning $\to$  vs $\mapsto$ the first link gives some hints, but it should be clear that it is a good idea to distinguish between the mapping of a space/group etc on to a new space/group etc and the mapping of a specific member/point onto the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is explained in the article mikuszefski cites in a comment, but can be understood in a fairly intuitive way via the $\phi$ with the curved arrow at the top of the picture.

Without reference to the notation, just looking at the curved arrow, $\phi$ is a function that maps one big region to another, and in particular the sub-region $X$ to the sub-region $x.$

The authors formalize this idea with two lines:

$\phi: R_X \times [t_0,t_f]\to R_x\times [t_0,t_f] $

$(X_0,t)\mapsto \phi(X,t)=(x,t) $

These can be read, respectively, as:

"$\phi$ maps the region $R_X$ in the time interval $[t_0,t_f]$ to the region $R_x$ during the same time interval."

"$(X,t)$ is mapped by the function $\phi$ to $(x,t).$"

I don't think the English is fixed in stone. While it may be standard in this context, I think the notation $\times$ is very confusing. It is meant to associate a time interval with the regions, but of course the symbol is loaded with other associations for someone embroiled in vector calculus.

There may be conventions regarding $\mapsto$ and $\to.$ Readers of the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation) can decide whether the distinctions are meaningful or worth fussing about.